# Instagram API POST not calling GET

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm running into an issue with the Instagram API.  I have an API endpoint set up that will allow me to retrieve photos with a given hastag:

Docs:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

GET Request:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

That's working fine.  and when I make that get request (or refresh the page if i'm already on it) I can see the new object in the response.  I'm trying to figure out how to make Instagram make a call to me when this object changes.  I've followed the documentation here:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

and I can make the connection and see that I've successfully subscribed, but my GET route is never called when a new photo with a specific hash is added.  I've been at this for hours so I'm really hoping this is something simple I'm overlooking.

One other thing I can mention is that after running my curl command:

From what I can tell, I'm supposed to wire up to:

```
curl -F 'client_id=XXX' \
     -F 'client_secret=XXX' \
     -F 'object=tag' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=XXXX' \
     -F 'callback_url=https://XXX/api/xyz/' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

The documentation states that I should be able to list my subscriptions by going to: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET&client_id=CLIENT-ID` but when i do, i just see an empty `data` array.  Something is clearly going on but I can't figure out what. I've been reading up and down the documentation but can't find anything.

Comment: So another thing i just found out is that `object=tag` does not work, but doing `object=user` will give me the behavior that i want ONLY when the specific users posts, I'm trying to get a post by hashtag.